# how to handle large dataset like sproutcore

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I really don't have any substantial code to show here, actually, that's kinda why I am writing: I looked at the SproutCore demo, especially the Collection demo, on http://demo.sproutcore.com/sample_controls/, and am amazed by its loading 200,000 records to the page so easily. I tried using Rails to provide 200,000 records and in a completely blank HTML page with 
<% @projects.each do |p| %>
 <%= p.title %>
<% end %>
that freezes the browser for seconds on my m1530 laptop with 4gb ram and t7700 256gb ssd.

Yet the sproutcore demo does not freeze and takes less than 3 seconds to load.

What do you think the one technique they are using to enable this is?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really ontopic: But is the design used in the demo ruby-specific or something? Where do they get their UI tools?

Comment: In the tutorial, SproutCore seems to me to be a gem. So yes, maybe it is a ruby framework. Some blogs says Apple uses it in conjunction with Apple's own code to write MobileMe.

Comment: I guess it uses local browser db rather than a server side db. Extract from http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/desktop-like-web-applications-with-sproutcore/ : "Like other JavaScript frameworks, SproutCore  has ready to use visual widgets like list views, button views, and forms. But it also has other functions such as an in-memory database (that can integrate with "client-side offline storage"), bindings, property observing, and controllers." Reading 200,000 records takes the same time for any backend as its based on HTTP requests.

Comment: And if it uses client-side offline storage then yes it just takes less than 3 secs to load as there is no HTTP requests involved in the process at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the demo provided isn't being generated dynamically - it's static data.

Very few systems would be able to iterate a collection of live data that size. There are a number of techniques including streaming the dataset (using batch iteration through the records) through to caching and ajax partial loading strategies.

Comment: But with 200,000 data, even if you do an ajax call for ever 1000, that's 200 calls, it probably wouldn't get done in 5 seconds. If you do 10,000 each, that might fit the ajax calls in 5 seconds, but I tried loading 10,000 just <span>Hello World</span> from a Rails app, that took a while to just show up on the screen and I don't think my computer is that slow. To think putting 20X more that quickly...

Comment: True, loading with ajax would take many smaller calls. The point I was making is that the data isn't being loaded in that demo ... it's a static file with the 200k entries, which should be pretty blazing on any system.

Comment: Do you mean to say that it is one hugh abc.html file with those entries already in place?? You know, haha, I never thought about that

Answer (score 2):

The technology that SproutCore uses to display and scroll smoothly through "infinite" lists of data has very little to do with where the data comes from and almost all to do with the integration of special SproutCore view classes, `SC.CollectionView` (the parent class of `SC.ListView` and `SC.GridView`) and `SC.ScrollView`; the collection of powerful client side datastore classes: `SC.Store` and `SC.SparseArray`; and the SproutCore runtime and controller architecture.

The fact is that you simply cannot render a list of several hundred thousand items in it and expect the browser not to grind to a halt.  That is too many elements to insert into the DOM tree and that is why `SC.CollectionView` is optimized to *only generate elements for the currently showing items in the list* (ex. if only 20 items are visible out of 20 million, only 20 elements are in the DOM).  It gets even better than that though, because by default as items scroll in and out of view, the few existing elements are *updated in place with the new item information so that the DOM tree is not even touched*.  This would not be possible though without the integration of `SC.ScrollView` that allows the collection to be aware of its visible rect and when a scroll is about to happen.

On top of that, there is the entire SproutCore runtime architecture which is used to ensure that all DOM manipulations are queued up so that you *only touch the DOM once per run loop if needed* when a display property changes (ex. toggling a display property 50 times in one run loop only touches the DOM once with the final value).  This is an important factor in extreme performance that affects all SproutCore views including `SC.CollectionView`.

Finally, to make the list really scream, you cannot load several million items into the client in one request, nor can you even store them all in client memory.  This leads me to another optimization of `SC.CollectionView` and the SproutCore data store, which is to *work with sparse data*.  `SC.CollectionView` will never try to iterate over every item in its content, so it doesn't need all the data present, only what is being shown.  When we load data into the client, we would use an `SC.SparseArray` to page in a bit of data at a time as needed.  The whole system is very elegantly designed so that when the collection view requests an item that the sparse array doesn't yet have, the sparse array fetches it (or the next page of items) in the background.  Because of bindings and observers, when the new data comes in we can update the list in place, which means that the *scrolling doesn't block while data is being brought in*.

That demo above is very outdated, here is a new one that uses the technologies I mentioned above: http://showcase.sproutcore.com/#demos/Big%20Data (source is here: https://github.com/sproutcore/demos/tree/master/apps/big_data).  In this demo, I scroll through *50,000 names*, which is all I could generate and split into 500 JSON files of a 100 names each that are loaded remotely from the server.  Once you scroll past 100 names, you will see that the next 100 names are paged in and there is a brief flash of placeholder text "…" (how long you see the placeholder text depends on your Internet connection).

I used 50,000 names, but I *don't see any problem showing a list of 500,000 or 5 million names* though.  However, at that scale you would want to also 'un-page' data as you bring in new data using `SC.Store#unloadRecords` to keep the memory use down.

There's a few other technologies in play to make this whole thing possible that I've missed, but those are the main ones at least.

Answer (score 0):

More on sproutcore here.. http://ostatic.com/blog/sproutcore-raises-the-bar-for-client-side-programming

If on the other hand you are looking for concurrency then node.js is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Shripad. Correct me if I get this wrong, I thought only Webkit or ,even more narrowly, Safari has client-side db storage using, best of my guess, Sqlite? That demo works on Firefox and IE8 as well!